# Is this a Typescript construct, inside a .js file? And how do I deal with it?

Tags: javascript, typescript, babeljs, mapbox-gl-js

I'm attempting to get a simple test running, but Babel 7 complains ....

The full error message is:

```
 SyntaxError: /Users/malcolm/git/walks/node_modules/mapbox-gl/src/util/window.js: Unexpected token (9:12)

   7 | import { extend } from './util';
   8 | 
>  9 | import type {Window} from '../types/window';
     |             ^
  10 | 
  11 | const { window: _window } = new jsdom.JSDOM('', {
  12 |     virtualConsole: new jsdom.VirtualConsole().sendTo(console)

  at Parser.raise (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:3939:15)
  at Parser.unexpected (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:5248:16)
  at Parser.expectContextual (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:5216:41)
  at Parser.parseImport (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:8429:12)
  at Parser.parseStatementContent (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:7234:27)
  at Parser.parseStatement (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:7153:17)
  at Parser.parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:7707:23)
  at Parser.parseBlockBody (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:7694:10)
  at Parser.parseTopLevel (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:7118:10)
  at Parser.parse (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:8521:17)
```

The offending line (below) looks like it might be a little piece of Typescript but I'm no expert.

`import type {Window} from '../types/window';`

But what is it doing in a .js file? I thought Typescript belonged in .ts files?

I'd like to get this compiled (with Babel 7) so that my little test starts running, but I am presuming that `@babel/preset-typescript` is hovering about looking for **.ts** files and isn't going to do anything about this line inside a **.js** file.

The complete file containing this line is here:

> https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/master/src/util/window.js

Can anybody shed a little light on this for me?

- What is this line and why doesn't Babel like it?

Comment: What is the word `type` doing in line 9?

Comment: [Appears to be using Flow](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/modules/) rather than TypeScript.

Comment: If I isolate line 9 into a typescript file, it generates multiple errors, so I think it is not valid TypeScript.

Comment: The library already has a build process to strip this type of thing out: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/03f877526dc052f90b5c710d90ef2d7d886fbced/build/rollup_plugins.js#L44 Why are you trying to duplicate that?

Comment: @loganfsmyth that explains it, thankyou. If you’d like to put it as an answer, I’ll tick it. You have saved me from wasting further time on the line of thiught I was following.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a snippet of code with [Flowtype](https://flow.org/) annotations. This project [already has a build process](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/03f877526dc052f90b5c710d90ef2d7d886fbced/build/rollup_plugins.js#L44) that strips out these annotations though, so I don't think you should be consuming these `src/` files directly.